# OBSF4 and scramblesuit

Tags: tails, pluggable-transports, obfs4

It seems I can't connect to OBSF4 or scramblesuit bridges with TAILS. I have no troubble with OBSF3 in Tails. Below is some of the error message. Can you guys help me out? Thanks.

```
10/08/2016 08:32:03.600 [NOTICE] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1. 
10/08/2016 08:32:04.100 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
10/08/2016 08:32:04.100 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050 
10/08/2016 08:32:04.100 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9061 
10/08/2016 08:32:04.100 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9062 
10/08/2016 08:32:04.100 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
10/08/2016 08:32:04.100 [NOTICE] Opening DNS listener on 127.0.0.1:5353 
10/08/2016 08:32:04.100 [NOTICE] Opening Transparent pf/netfilter listener on 127.0.0.1:9040 
10/08/2016 08:32:04.100 [NOTICE] Renaming old configuration file to "/etc/tor/torrc.orig.1" 
10/08/2016 08:32:05.000 [NOTICE] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1. 
10/08/2016 08:32:06.500 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
10/08/2016 08:32:06.600 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
10/08/2016 08:33:06.700 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 194.132.209.97:55597 ("server rejected connection") 
10/08/2016 08:33:06.700 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 192.36.31.56:35990 ("server rejected connection") 
10/08/2016 08:34:13.800 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 69.162.169.213:24848 ("server rejected connection") 
10/08/2016 08:34:17.300 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Transparent pf/netfilter listener on 127.0.0.1:9040 
10/08/2016 08:34:17.300 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured DNS listener on 127.0.0.1:5353 
10/08/2016 08:34:17.300 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050 
10/08/2016 08:34:17.300 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9061 
10/08/2016 08:34:17.300 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9062 
10/08/2016 08:34:17.300 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
10/08/2016 08:34:17.300 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
10/08/2016 08:34:17.300 [NOTICE] Closing old Transparent pf/netfilter listener on 127.0.0.1:9040 
10/08/2016 08:34:17.300 [NOTICE] Closing old DNS listener on 127.0.0.1:5353 
10/08/2016 08:34:17.300 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050 
10/08/2016 08:34:17.300 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9061 
10/08/2016 08:34:17.300 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9062 
10/08/2016 08:34:17.300 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
```

Comment: Could you try to retrieve other bridge adresses and connect to them. Does this work?

Comment: I have tried several of each only obsf3 works.

Comment: Can I get some more help here? Using Tails>More options>being cencorsed by isp> only osbf3 works? Is osbf3 comprmised?

Comment: obfs3 can be broken by an active MITM but it only strips the obfuscation, not the security of the underlying OR connection. have you tried fetching a fresh set of obfs4 bridges?

Comment: Yes I have tried several, sould I try 1-2 at a time or is there some special config I need to do in tails?

Answer (score 1):

My little trick to connect to more obfs4 bridges in TAILS:

First collect some working bridges via bridge DB (e.g. obfs3) or connect to regular tor.

When connected cut the connection in the on/off menu.

Reconnect.

While reconnecting quickly click to connect via bridges and enter your obfs4 bridge relays.

TAILS now connects to obfs4 bridges that were at first rejected.

You'll have to be quick and need a little practise.

Have fun!